# XAMPP Installing

Tags: php, xampp

I am installing XAMPP and have encountered the following problem:

> Important! Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your
>   system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted.
>
> With UAC please avoid to install XAMPP to C:\Program Files(Missing
>   Write permissions). Or Deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup.

Can you help me what is the problem?

Comment: Uninstall and re-Install to a different directory.

Comment: what is the problem? everything is said in that message ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Web server's don't have right to access files from program files, the public directory Htdocs needs full control,

Program files come under Windows Operating System Directory and it has limited access So it will give Error.

> Run as administrator is helpful to install but when you publish your website every time you have to change file permission for every file because in C:/program files/ directory have limited access.

For Install Xampp you have to select the location which has full access:
Example: You can choose c:/Xampp or any other directory D:/

Answer (score 0):

This is default message when UAC is activated, it shouldn't bother you at all. But if you are paroniod about it do the following

1. Uninstall xammp
2. In the search bar on the start menu or search menu type "uac" or "user access control"
3. Click into it then move the scroll bar to "Never notify"
4. Click ok and you may have to log off or restart for it to take affect
5. Reinstall xammp and once it's installed you can change the UAC setting back to how they were, I personally leave it off as it's annoying.

Oh and make it "Run as Administrator" just incase

Answer (score -1):

ignore this message and install xampp on C:\xampp, all services will work